# Unexpected Flexy Error

Tags: error-handling

Error by loading page (using XAMPP)

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::raiseError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\pear\HTML\Template\Flexy.php on line 692
    Could not open the template: ''
    Please check the file permissions on the directory and file
```

I do't understand this Error. What does it mean and what did I wrong?
Could it be, that ther's a NO GO in my template part?

I'm not sure about this in my temlate, can I do it and is it right?

```
<form action="{formaction}">
    <table>
    {foreach:form,f}
       <tr>
           <td>{f.desc}</td>
           <td>
           {if:f.textarea}
               <textarea name="{f.type}" cols="{f.cols}" rows="{f.rows}">{f.value}</textarea>{end:}
           {if:f.checkradio}
               {foreach:f.checkradio,c}
                   <input type="{f.type}" name="{f.name}" value="{f.value}" {c.choosed}>{end:}
           {if: f.numrange}
               <input type="{f.type}" name="{f.name}" value="{f.value}" min="{f.min}" max="{f.max}">{end:}
           {if: f.normal}
               <input type="{f.type}" name="{f.name}" value="{f.value}" min="{f.min}" max="{f.max}">{end:}
           </td>
      </tr>{end:}
   </table>
</form>
```